# Togglesclass doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented the code for detecting the cookie on the domain.

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("temp") >= 0) {
  $(".hideme").toggleClass("hide");
}
else {
    alert("Yo you don have cookie bro!");
}
```

Here is the Html

```
<div id="wrapper" class="hideme">

</div>
```

As you can see i want to toggle class into a div but it doesn't work for me. No error on console

What is wrong with my code?
Did i miss any semicolon or something?

PS: Cookie exist in the browser.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code from what I can see. What's likely wrong is not in what you posted. Did you define class hide? Perhaps you should just call `.hide()`

Comment: @DanielCook You right, i just forgot to put the code after the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `toggleClass()` here, it should just be `addClass()` as you're not expecting to keep flip-flopping the class. (*Make sure that you have a class called 'hide' defined in your CSS.*)

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("temp") != -1) {
  $(".hideme").addClass("hide");
}
else {
    alert("Yo you don have cookie bro!");
}
```

In addition you want to test for the truthiness of `indexOf()`. Just make sure it isn't equal to -1 and you're good to go. (*If the indexOf() is equal to zero then it is true because arrays can begin at 0*.)

Comment: For this situation `>= 0` is logically equivalent to `!= -1` because `indexOf()` returns either a number >= 0 or -1.

Comment: True @DanielCook, but conventionally most JS developers test against the -1 value rather than >=0.

Comment: I'd love to see where the convention is written. I usually just do `~...indexOf()` if I'm doing a Boolean check.

Comment: Right here - [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) There is nothing wrong with the way that you check it either - different styles for different folks...like curly brackets and semi-colons.